# Why does the OE form "byrht" appear?

Tags: old-english

Why does the OE form "byrht" appear?
OE should have beorht (West Saxon) or berht (Anglian). Is it Kentish form or what?
also byrc, fyht

Comment: Old English is a lot less uniform than you appear to give it credit for. Anglian was itself sub-divided into three major dialects (Mercian, Northumbrian, and East Anglian), and all dialects varied over time. I know Late West Saxon underwent a shift of /iy/ > /y/, I wonder if the /eo/ of beorht could have ended up raising to /iy/ in some varieties of West Saxon, going on to become byrht through monophthongisation

Comment: @Tristan There were both _*-ī_ and _-ū_-derivatives of _*berht-_ (e.g., [bierhtu](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bierhtu)), which would be likely to raise the vowel more or less everywhere. The raised vowel could then be carried through to the base word analogically as a variant form.